# How do I know if docker image build with inline cache?

Tags: docker

[Docker documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

> the builder can reuse the cache generated from previous builds with the --cache-from flag pointing to an image in the registry.

> To use an image as a cache source, cache metadata needs to be written into the image on creation. This can be done by setting --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 when building the image.

However, I noticed that I can still use `docker build --cache-from` with images which were built without inline cache. In this case docker builds new image without any warnings or error messages. Therefore, I wonder what's the real difference between images built with inline cache and without it? And how do I know if source image was built with inline cache or not?

Answer (score -1):

the cache is used to avoid repeat instructions like COPY, RUN etc. If you already have cache for you image there are not difference, you will only notice if you clean the cache for you image first.

If you are building a large image y you wish it didn't take too long, I recommend to you build a docker image base.

for example: image base `dockerfile` with a very large requirements.txt

```
FROM python:3.9.5-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libxmlsec1-dev pkg-config && apt-get install -y tzdata

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 8000
```

image base `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  python-base:
    networks: 
      - services-net
    image: myrepo/python-base:0.0.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

and then you use it like this:

concrete docker file

```
FROM myrepo/python-base:0.0.1
...
```

**Finally you can push your base image to dockerhub and use it from anywhere**

Comment: I probably not formulated the question precisely, but I it's not "how does cache in docker work?" kind of question. I understand how it works and why it is needed. My question is specifically about BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE: how do I know if image was build with this option or not?